# Help with medieval medical passage

Tags: medieval-latin

I am trying to make out parts of an early 15th century medical manuscript that is barely visible. I make out a line that possibly says: (look below)

"CAUTE DERECTE IRINI O TERO"

OR

"CAUTE DERECTE IRINI E TERO"

Should these lines be read from right to left instead?

Do either of these lines make sense?

Please help!
Thanks

Comment: A picture would be very helpful: as written these lines don't make syntactical sense, though some words in your transcription individually make sense.

Comment: Are you at least confident of the word spacing?  Also, more context beyond a "medical text" might be helpful in guessing words.  Each of the words could be meaningful in Latin individually, but together they cannot even be translated because they do not hang together enough to come up with a subject and predicate that match or even make much sense individually outside of context.